# pgfplots line colors

Tags: pgfplots, color

Is it possible to make `pgfplots` use a predefined color map while plotting multiple lines, I currently have 9 samples that I want to plot, but don't want to type different colors for each one. Right now they are all showing up as black. Let me know if this is possible, thanks!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use `cycle list name=<list>`. there are few pre-defined lists --

1. `color`  (from top to bottom)
2. `exotic`
3. `black white`
4. `mark list`
5. `mark list*`
6. `linestyles`
7. `linestyles*`
8. `auto`

If you want you can create your own list like

```
\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{mycolorlist}{%
blue,every mark/.append style={fill=blue!80!black},mark=*\\%
red,every mark/.append style={fill=red!80!black},mark=square*\\%
brown!60!black,every mark/.append style={fill=brown!80!black},mark=otimes*\\%
black,mark=star\\%
blue,every mark/.append style={fill=blue!80!black},mark=diamond*\\%
red,densely dashed,every mark/.append style={solid,fill=red!80!black},mark=*\\%
brown!60!black,densely dashed,every mark/.append style={
solid,fill=brown!80!black},mark=square*\\%
black,densely dashed,every mark/.append style={solid,fill=gray},mark=otimes*\\%
blue,densely dashed,mark=star,every mark/.append style=solid\\%
red,densely dashed,every mark/.append style={solid,fill=red!80!black},mark=diamond*\\%
}
```

and use it as `cycle list name=mylist`.

Code (taken from `pgfplots` manual):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
stack plots=y,stack dir=minus,
cycle list name=color list]
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @cmhughes For the code given above, yes, it is the expected output (same in manual also) :)

Comment: oh, I see that you didn't actually *use* the cycle list that you created :)

Comment: @cmhughes No, It is just `color list` which is pre-defined. :)

Comment: `auto` _seems_ to be the default. As usual the problem with automatic list is that eventually they hit yellow. :)

Comment: Note that `\addplot[<additional options>]` ignores the `color list`. If you need to add option(s), you can use `\addplot+[<options]`.
Also note that, unlike `\draw`, `\addplot[\color]` is not compatible with `\foreach \color in {blue, red, green}` since it gathers only the coordinates but no style options in the "survey phase" (see https://www.mrunix.de/forums/showthread.php?75727-Schleife-%FCber-Farben-in-pgfplots)

Answer (score 6):

With the release of PGFPlots v1.13 it is much easier to define `cycle list`s, because now there exist much more possibilities. For example `cycle list`s can be combined from other `cycle list`s. With that you can define your "default" color `cycle list` and then combine it with others to fit certain requirements.

Here you can see an example using the `cycle multiindex* list` key. For more have a look at [section 4.7.7 on page 194 of the PGFPlots manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=194).

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{
        pgfplots.colorbrewer,
    }
    \pgfplotsset{
        % define a `cycle list' for marker
        cycle list/.define={my marks}{
            every mark/.append style={solid,fill=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/mark list fill}},mark=*\\
            every mark/.append style={solid,fill=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/mark list fill}},mark=square*\\
            every mark/.append style={solid,fill=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/mark list fill}},mark=triangle*\\
            every mark/.append style={solid,fill=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/mark list fill}},mark=diamond*\\
        },
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            % load a color `cycle list' from the `colorbrewer' library
            cycle list/RdGy-6,
            % define fill color for the marker
            mark list fill={.!75!white},
            % create new `cycle list` from existing `cycle list's and an
            cycle multiindex* list={
                RdGy-6
                    \nextlist
                my marks
                    \nextlist
                [3 of]linestyles
                    \nextlist
                very thick
                    \nextlist
            },
            samples=3,
            legend entries={0,...,20},
            legend pos=outer north east,
        ]
            \addplot {x};
            \addplot {x-1};
            \addplot {x-2};
            \addplot {x-3};
            \addplot {x-4};
            \addplot {x-5};
            \addplot {x-6};
            \addplot {x-7};
            \addplot {x-8};
            \addplot {x-9};
            \addplot {x-10};
            \addplot {x-11};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]