# How to use a command inside \addplot options

Tags: pgfplots, expansion, loops

How can I use a command inside an `\addplot` option?  My guess is that I'd have to find the right expansion order.

The example below illustrates the problem.  I'm *not* looking for a workaround (which I can do myself), but for something that uses the right combination of `\expandafter` and similar commands.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\foreach \L/\C in {-8/Red,-4/Magenta,-2/Pink,0/Black,2/Beige,4/LightGreen,8/Green} 
 \addplot[smooth,domain=0:1,color=\C]{ \L*x)  };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: And yes, I've seen https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170221/pgfplots-line-colors

Comment: The standard `\edef\temp{\noexpand\draw ...} \temp` trick described in the `pgfplots` manual works.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17638/pgfplots-foreach-equivalent-to-tikzs-with-multiple-variables-separated-by-a-sla/17817#17817

Comment: Another way (at least here): `\expandafter\addplot\expandafter[\C,smooth,domain=0:1]{ \L*x)  };`.

Comment: @Mike 's solution is closest to what I am after, thanks.

Comment: You should be aware, that @TorbjørnT.'s suggestion is better, because it also works with more variables in `[...]` and with `color=\C`. Mine only works, because the color can be given without `color=`.

Answer (score 5):

Too long for a comment, and possibly off-topic, but well. Using another kind of loop you will not have to do any `\expandafter` or `\edef` manoeuvers (the former not being always really feasible, or requiring dozens `\expandafter`'s).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{xinttools}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  \xintForpair #1#2 in {(-8, Red), (-4, Magenta), (-2, Pink), (0, Black), (2,
    Beige), (4, LightGreen), (8, Green)} 
\do {\addplot[smooth,domain=0:1,color=#2]{#1*x) };}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The syntax isn't as `\foreach`'s and in particular `1, 3, ..., 10` kind of syntax is not supported, but it does have more cumbersome equivalent for numbers but not for letters though (I think  `\foreach` accepts `a, b, ..., f`).

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  I always like learning new ways of doing things.

Comment: much appreciated `;-)`