# Color lists not working in foreach loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, color

I'm trying to plot the beta prime distribution, which is defined for `x>0` with the two parameters α and β, having the probability density function:

[image]

I'm trying to plot a graph like this:

[image]

see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_prime_distribution

This is what I have so far:

[image]

I can't get the colours to work, even though I am using `cycle list name` as shown in this question - [pgfplots line colors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170221/pgfplots-line-colors?noredirect=1&lq=1)

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
%
xmin=0,xmax=5,
ymin=0,ymax=2,
cycle list name = auto,
samples=100]

\foreach \A/\B/\C in {%
    1/1/1,
    1/2/0.5,
    2/1/0.5,
    2/2/0.1667,
    2/3/0.0833,
    5/3/0.009524}{%
\addplot[domain=0:5] {((x^(\A-1))*(1+x)^(-\A-\B))/\C};
}
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've just realised the thing that was missing was a `+` after `\addplot`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that it is possible if you insert a cycle of color: here there is your revised MWE. The symbols `%<------` correspond to my additions.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{fycle}{%  %<------
    {blue}, %<------
    {orange},%<------
    {red},%<------
    {green},%<------
}%<------

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
%
xmin=0,xmax=5,
ymin=0,ymax=2,
cycle list name = fycle,
samples=100]

\foreach \A/\B/\C in {%
    1/1/1,
    1/2/0.5,
    2/1/0.5,
    2/2/0.1667,
    2/3/0.0833,
    5/3/0.009524}{%
\addplot+[domain=0:5] {((x^(\A-1))*(1+x)^(-\A-\B))/\C};%<------ only %\addplot+
}
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```