# Using a color series in pgfplots cycle list

Tags: pgfplots, color

I know that I can define a new cycle list for `pgfplots` using `\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist` if I provide an explicit list of the colors I want to cycle through. How can I instead use a color series defined using `xcolor`'s `\definecolorseries`, i.e. cycle through that color series?

MWE for testing:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

% Define a color series.
\definecolorseries{foo}{hsb}{step}[hsb]{0,1,1}[hsb]{.618,0,0}
\resetcolorseries{foo}

% Now use that color series in a cycle list.
\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{mylist}{}

\begin{document}

{\color{foo!![6]}Hello}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis} [
        stack plots=y,
        stack dir=minus,
        cycle list name=mylist,
      ]
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: See this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/170221/4778 (I think it's a duplicate personally), but also this can be helpful https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/268044/4778

Comment: @Alenanno As far as I can see, those questions and answers only use explicit color lists. They do not address how to use a color series for a cycle list at all.

Comment: The accepted answer for the first one mentions automatic lists where you do not need to define the colors of the list. Those are pre-defined. And then also mentions explicitly defined lists.

Comment: If that doesn't answer your question, can you clarify that part for me? Do you want to define two colors and let `pgfplots` color going from the first to the second color while plotting?

Comment: No, it mentions _predefined_ lists, which are still defined by enumerating colors/styles. That is not a color series.

Comment: @Alenanno I want to use a _color series_, defined using `\definecolorseries`, as shown in the MWE. I'm not sure how to make that any clearer.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/293917/227987 does *not* use explicitly defined colors. Rather it uses the `colorbrewer` library (see section **5.2 ColorBrewer** of the pgfplots v1.17 manual) to define something that is very similar to your request, but arguably more powerful.

Comment: @anonymous Could you elaborate on how the `colorbrewer` cycle lists are not made up of predefined colors?

Comment: Section 5.2 starts with an explicit example, and the linked post has an example. You may get confused because it combines different possibilities. BTW, you can also look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/286837/227987 to see how you can get a color from a colormap.

Comment: Here is an explicit example: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[cycle list/GnBu-9,cycle multi list={GnBu-9}]
  \pgfplotsforeachungrouped\icol in {1,...,9}   
    {\addplot coordinates {(0,1-\icol) (0.5,1-\icol) (1,1-\icol)};
 }
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Answer (score 4):

Not only the line color, cycle list in `pgfplots` can also control other aspects like the drawing patten, marker shape and marker options. The following example sets color series `foo` (the actually used color-spec is `foo!![<n>]`) as drawing color. You may also want to use `foo` as the current color of that series in marker options.

Noted that `pgf` currently does not has full support for hsb color model and you will get `` ! Package pgf Error: Unsupported color model `hsb'. Sorry. `` from `every mark/.append style={fill=foo!80!black}`.

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

% Define a color series.
\definecolorseries{foo}{hsb}{step}[hsb]{0,1,1}[hsb]{.618,0,0}
\resetcolorseries{foo}

% Now use that color series in a cycle list.
\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{mylist}{
  % based on cycle list "color"
  {foo!![0]},every mark/.append style={fill=blue!80!black},mark=*\\
  {foo!![1]},every mark/.append style={fill=red!80!black},mark=square*\\
  {foo!![2]},every mark/.append style={fill=brown!80!black},mark=otimes*\\
  {foo!![3]},mark=star\\
  {foo!![4]},every mark/.append style={fill=blue!80!black},mark=diamond*\\
  {foo!![5]},densely dashed,every mark/.append style={solid,fill=red!80!black},mark=*\\
  {foo!![6]},densely dashed,every mark/.append style={solid,fill=brown!80!black},mark=square*\\
  {foo!![7]},densely dashed,every mark/.append style={solid,fill=gray},mark=otimes*\\
  {foo!![8]},densely dashed,mark=star,every mark/.append style=solid\\
  {foo!![9]},densely dashed,every mark/.append style={solid,fill=red!80!black},mark=diamond*\\
}

\begin{document}

For testing and checking:\par
{\ttfamily
  \foreach \i in {0,1,...,4} { \textcolor{foo!!+}{foo!![\i]} }\par
  \foreach \i in {5,6,...,9} { \textcolor{foo!!+}{foo!![\i]} }
}

\resetcolorseries{foo}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis} [
        stack plots=y,
        stack dir=minus,
        cycle list name=mylist,
      ]
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
    \addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When using `foo!!+` as the color like this, every other color in the series is skipped. This makes me suspect that this color is invoked more than once per line and I will run into trouble at some point because something that should have the same color as the line does not. Do you know where the second invocation occurs and how to avoid problems?

Comment: @schtandard Answer is updated to use `foo!![<n>]` directly. This restricts the "color series" used in color list to be finite, while a real color series could be infinite.

Comment: Hmm, I was afraid, this would be the tradeoff.. Anyway, thanks for looking into this. By the way, the `hsb` warning can be avoided by passing the `rgb` option to `xcolor`.